# Integrate a polymorphic extendable sorting order

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, polymorphism

Suppose I have a base class `B`, and two derived classes `C`, `D`.

If I put objects of `C` and `D` in a vector, I can sort the vector by type by overloading the lessThan operator to take two objects of type `B` and do the necessary comparisons in there. For instance I can give each class a sorting ID and compare that to determine, if `C` comes before `D` or vice versa. 
Let's assume now the sorting order is `C`<`D`.
Suppose I want to be able to add an arbitrary amount of derived classes. Now while it still holds, that `C`<`D`, there might now be a class `E` that requires `C`<`E`<`D`.

Hence, how would I implement such an extendable sorting order, without needing to change `C` and `D`, when I add a new class `E`?

Comment: There's really no simple way to do it. The simplest is to add more `operator<` function overloads, or add custom functors or functions that you pass to `std::sort`, to be able to handle all the different sortings and combinations of objects. Unless you take care during design it might quickly become quite a large number of functions, which is why I recommend you take a step back and look over your design and see if you can improve it (even if it means changes to the existing classes).

Comment: Is it feasable to make the sorting index a double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked but... what about putting in the vector a pair with the sorting ID and a `B` ?

I mean... if you define an `enum` for sorting IDs

```
enum idClass { isB, isC, isD };
```

and a type using to make shorter the code

```
using pib = std::pair<idClass, B>;
```

you can define the vector as follows

```
std::vector<pib> vpb;
```

add elements remembering the correct ID

```
vpb.emplace_back(isC, C{});
vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});
```

and sorting with the use of a simple lambda

```
std::sort(vpb.begin(), vpb.end(), [](pib const & p1, pib const & p2)
          { return p1.first < p2.first; });
```

When you add another class `E`, you have only to add an `isE` ID in the `idClass` enum (in the position you prefer) and there is no need to modify `B`, `C` or `D`.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct B { };
struct C : public B { };
struct D : public B { };

enum idClass { isB, isC, isD };

int main ()
 {
   using pib = std::pair<idClass, B>;

   std::vector<pib> vpb;

   vpb.emplace_back(isC, C{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isC, C{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isC, C{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});
   vpb.emplace_back(isD, D{});


   std::sort(vpb.begin(), vpb.end(), [](pib const & p1, pib const & p2)
             { return p1.first < p2.first; });

   for ( auto const & p : vpb )
      std::cout << "- " << p.first << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: I like this approach